# Keep scroll position after wishlist add

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist, ce-1.9.2.4, position

I have a page with products, and when I add a product to the wishlist or shopping cart, my screen jumps to the top of the page.

Is there a way I can stay at the same scrollposition after I add a product to my cart or wishlist from my category page.

Comment: Have you using infinite scroll of your product page

Comment: I don't need an infinite scroll on my page (you mean this extension, right? Strategery - InfiniteScroll) I just need to stay at the same scroll position after I add an item to my wishlist or shopping cart.

Comment: There may be a "#" symbol as href on those links. This can trigger this behavior. Check for this.

Comment: There isn't a "#" in the link. And even if it would been, I still need to figure out how to trigger a method on that anchor link.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out using jquery.

code :

```
//  Get the scrollposition after adding a product to the wishlist or shopping cart

//Loading the document
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        // If scroll location cookie is set, and the location is the same
        //scroll to the position saved in the scroll cookie.
            if ( jQuery.cookie("scroll") !== null && jQuery.cookie("location") !== null 
                    && jQuery.cookie("location") == jQuery(location).attr('href')) {
                jQuery(document).scrollTop( jQuery.cookie("scroll") );
            }

                jQuery("#grid").click(function () {
                    // Set cookie with current location
                    jQuery.cookie("location", jQuery(location).attr('href'));
                    // Set cookie with current scrollposition from the top
                    jQuery.cookie("scroll", jQuery(document).scrollTop() );
                });
});
```

Comment: Great solution! Works like a charm for Magento 2.3.3